# Catch does not report an error when mysqli INSERT fails.

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, exception, try-catch

I am sure this is a basic mistake but several hours on I am still stumped. I have looked through about a dozen "catch not working" and none seem useful.

I inherited this bit of code. ALL the variables have values (though some are empty strings). More than the basic problem here I am worried that my `catch` is not catching errors (previously the statement was trying to store a value in a column that did not exist and even that did not throw an exception).

I have this at the top. (I tried initially with the two statements together but that gave a problem – can’t remember what.)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", ""); // private stuff taken out
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
```

This is the basic code

```
$packageResult = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO package (user_id,
package_name, weight, tracking_number, size_width, size_depth, size_height,
source, carrier, instructions, sent,ot48code) VALUES ({$_SESSION['id']},
'{$_POST['packageName']}', '{$_POST['weight']}', 
'{$_POST['tracking_number']}', '{$_POST['width']}', '{$_POST['depth']}', 
'{$_POST['height']}', '{$_POST['source']}', '{$_POST['carrier']}', 
'{$_POST['instructions']}',  NOW()),$ot48code");
```

I debugged a bit and, although the `$packageResult` comes back FALSE, the `catch` code is never accessed. (Using Xdebug in PhpStorm.)

```
 catch (Exception $e)
   {
  echo "<pre>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo "ses testing at 171";
  @var_dump($_SESSION);
  echo "<br>";
  ...
  echo $e->getMessage();
```

Is that right for `catch`?

(PS I know this is all horribly insecure but this is for an alpha and I am a slow typist and pretty awful programmer (no memory).)

Comment: From the doc: mysqli::query Returns FALSE on failure. So if it returns false there's no errors thrown by this method.

Comment: OK thanks ... Should I be saying something else instead of `exceptions`. PS Thanks for the lightening fast response! PPS I thought the `STRICT` forced that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To catch **ERRORS** as well as exceptions it seems you need

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);
```

That one line saved me.

I did think that:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
```

would do the job but ...

Hope this helps if you hit the same problem.

Big thanks to @pec.